# Fire javascript on a form submit

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

Even the searching I have done that looks like there may be a solution doesn't really seem to answer this.

I have a form with an input value.  When the user enters a value and clicks submit, I want to call a javascript routine and make that value available to it.

It seems simple enough, but I can't really find a good answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need some jQuery on the page, e.g:

```
Drupal.behaviors.form_submit_processor = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $("form#my-form").submit(function(e) {
      alert('form submitted');
      alert($('form#my-form #edit-name').val());
    });
  }
}
```

You could add to your theme `script.js`, with `drupal_add_js` or form_alter and `$form['#attached']` ( recommended )

Comment: My form keeps redirecting to another URL.  I changed the $form['#action'] value to url("#").  I'm not sure how to prevent Drupal from handling the submit and just let the JS handler deal with it.

Comment: When I event.preventDefault() after my event handler, it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can do this from Form API where you have access to the form directly. This enables complex behaviours and form alterations on AJAX calls.

Take a look at the [Ajax framework commands](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7). You'll need to enable AJAX in your form too. Sometimes this is as simple as adding the no-js path argument in `hook_menu` or adding the `use-ajax` class on links. Read up on the [AJAX framework](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7)  in Drupal and [ajaxifying forms](https://drupal.org/node/752056).

After the hook_form_submit you can then return an array of commands to run including the roll-your-own [ajax_command_invoke](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_invoke/7).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
Drupal.behaviors.form_submit_processor = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {

    // Function to be run before form submission
    var preFormSubmit = function () {
      // do some stuff here...
    }

    // Add a js function to run before form submission
    var formE = $('#my-form-id');
    formE
      .on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.when(preFormSubmit()).done(function () {
          formE
            .off('submit')
            .submit();
        });
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Using `$.when(preFormSubmit()).done` allows `preFormSubmit()` to finish before the form is submitted.