# Send form values to JS file

Tags: forms, 8

As clearly titled I want to send a **form values** to js file in **Drupal 8**.
I've made some researches and all I successfully coded was sending a PHP variable from a **Controller** to the JS file I'am using.

Here is the code:

*library_name.libraries.yml*

```
library_name:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/<js_file_name>.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

*controller_name.php (class)*

```
namespace Drupal\module_name\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;


class <class_name> extends ControllerBase {

  public function <method>(){

      return array(
        '#attached' => array(
            'library' => array(
            '<module_name>/<library_name>'
            ),
            'drupalSettings' => array(
                '<module_name>' => array(
                  '<library_name' => array(
                      'foo' => 'bar'
                  )
                )
            )
        )
      );

  }
```

*js_file_name.js (under /js folder)*

```
console.log(drupalSettings.<module_name>.<library_name>.foo);
```

Everything works great!

But how about using a **form**? I've declared a form extending from **FormBase** and in the **submitForm()** overridden method I typed the same array:

```
return array(
        '#attached' => array(
            'library' => array(
            '<module_name>/<library_name>'
            ),
            'drupalSettings' => array(
                '<module_name>' => array(
                  '<library_name' => array(
                      'foo' => 'bar'
                  )
                )
            )
        )
      );
```

I know this won't work! But any ideas? I thought about using another library, point to a js file there, and use that js file to get the form values  using the **#attached** tag like above, and then send those values to the other js file using **JSON**

If any one can provide me with a better **Drupal Standard**? that would be great! cause this my first time using Drupal.

---

***EDIT:***

I fixed this, using: the **module_name.settings.yml** file under **module_name/config/install** folder and also by using the **module_name.module** file where I've implemented the **hook_form_alter()** method.

So,

From my **module_name.module** file, here goes my code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */

function modulename_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){


     if($form_id === your_form_id){

        $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'module_name/route_name';
    // that's the route name you've defined in your module_name.libraries.yml file
    // where you've located the js file you're going to use

        $form['#attached']['drupalSettings']
        [module_name][route_name][send_this_variable_to_js] = \Drupal::config(module_name.settings)->get(key);

        return $form;
    }


}
```

Now in your JS file, you can **console.log** like this:

```
console.log(drupalSettings.module_name.route_name.server.send_this_variable_to_js)
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

You'll either need to add a js behavior that attaches itself to the normal submit event of the form, or create an AJAX Command that invokes a function in your script.

See: https://www.drupal.org/node/2290235

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the answer!
I am still in the same prob since yesterday, trying to find how can I pass through this using the Drupal API... which needs a LOT of time to get used to, for such a beginner like me.

Comment: I've made some changes, switching from FormBase to ConfigFormBase, and also saving all form data in a <module_name>.settings.yml file. However, I have a Javascript file that needs to handle the form data as well, and I am still trying to know what's the best way to do this. Thinking of parsing the YAML file using javascript... it's possible btw... however, I am still searching for a Drupal way to do this.

Comment: In that case, your form ajax submit needs to return an AjaxResponse, you can attach an InvokeCommand to call your jQuery method and pass data as arguments. See this answer which is similar (for D7 though): http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/193144/57

Comment: Also see: http://www.kalose.net/oss/drupal-8-ajax-forms/

Comment: Still nothing new Kevin. Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/khdVNJ3e, see the title.

Comment: Actually, I've made it, using another way :)

Comment: I don't see any Ajax in that code?

Comment: Well, it turns out that AJAX wasn't necessary LOL
Please review my EDIT post :)

Answer (score 1):

`#attached` only works on a page that is rendered. A form submission isn't, it's redirect and goes to some other page. It also doesn't have a return value.

You need to store this information somewhere, for example in the user session and then display it on the next page.

Alternatively, you could use $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE), store it with $form_state->set(), then buildForm() will be called again and you can add it there to $form. That's however usually only done when you actually explicitly want to keep the user "in" he form, somethink like an upload image or "add another" button.

Comment: Thanks for answering Berdir!
As I have wrote to Kevin, I've made some changes to my code, switching the form from FormBase to ConfigFormBase, and also saving all form data in a <module_name>.settings.yml file. However, I have a Javascript file that needs to handle the form data as well, and I am still trying to know what's the best way to do this. Thinking of parsing the YAML file using javascript... it's possible btw... however, I am still searching for a Drupal way to do this.

Comment: So you store the settings in yaml and then later on need to use it *somewhere* and send it to JS? That's not a problem, just access the config (in PHP, there is no way you can access that from JS), add it to drupalSettings and you're done?

Comment: Hi Bedir, Yes, and I want to send the Values from the **submitForm()** overriden method (myclass extends from **ConfigFormBase**), to make sure that the values are in the submit stage so they're safe to send. 
I tried to attach a js file for let's say debugging to make sure that I can add variables later, this line didn't work:

`$form['#attached']['library'][] = '<module_name>/<route_name>';`
`return parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);`

However in the **buildForm()** it worked

Comment: Thanks Berdid, I did likely the same solution you've pointed to.